# Type error: Profile object is not iterable

Tags: django

First time using a custom user model so I'm having trouble referencing the user object in views. I have tried a number of things but I'm really having difficulty grasping how to reference the user object within views with what I am trying to do.

**traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp/dating_app/views.py", line 120, in mingle
    description = Profile.objects.get(request.user).description
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1187, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 257, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
TypeError: 'Profile' object is not iterable
```

error is showing up here
**description = Profile.objects.get(request.user).description **

**views.py, part that's giving me an error **

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from dating_app.forms import RegistrationForm,ProfileUpdateForm
from .models import Profile

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os
from django.core import serializers
import json

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    User = get_user_model()


def mingle(request):

try:
    user = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
except IndexError:
    user = None
print(User.username)
try:
    description = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description
except models.Profile.DoesNotExist:
    create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
    return redirect('profile')

match = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).matches.all()
context = dict(user = user, match = match)  
return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings

class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,


)

user.set_password(password)
user.save(using=self._db)
return user 


def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        username=username,
        description=description,
        photo=photo,

    )

user.is_admin=True
user.is_staff=True
user.is_superuser=True
user.save(using=self._db)
return user

class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']

    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
django
shareedit delete flag
```

Comment: Can you share the trace back from the logs?

Comment: @IainShelvington Just did it

Comment: “ description = Profile.objects.get(request.user).description” is wrong, you need to use something like user=request.user

Comment: @IainShelvington lol dude, you told me to take user off in another post and leave it like that.          Here is what happens when I do that...   Exception Value: 
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, description, email, given_vote, id, is_active, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, matches, password, photo, username, uservote